# How to modify user profile properties using JavaScript in SharePoint 2013 (Online)?

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, sharepoint-online

I need to modify user profile properties using JavaScript (REST or CSOM). How can I do that?

I don't see any methods in [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.userprofiles.peoplemanager_members.aspx) about modifying profile properties without server code.

Thank you

**Update:**

I found that old .asmx user profile service works well, but in SharePoint Online I cannot grant permissions for my account to change all users properties, so I can edit using .asmx only my editable properties.
It is possible to grant permissions for account in on-premise SharePoint and edit all users properties from app, but this is not my case.

**Update:**
If you are interesting in solution I recommend above [there is stackexchange discussion](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/64361/how-can-i-pass-authentication-for-asmx-service-in-sharepoint-2013-online) about calling .asmx service with SharePoint Online

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Update as on 07/01/2014**

User profile properties are now writable via CSOM.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2014/11/07/sharepoint-user-profile-properties-now-writable-with-csom.aspx

Thanks to [Vardhaman Deshpande](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/3221/vardhaman-deshpande).

**Original Answer**

I am afraid if you can change User profile properties as stated by MSDN,

> User profile properties from client APIs are read-only (except the
>   profile picture, which you can change by using the
>   PeopleManager.setMyProfilePicture method). If you want to change other
>   user profile properties, you must use the server object model. For
>   more information about working with user profiles

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj920104.aspx)

If you want to change them through Server side code check this out,

[Work with user profiles in SharePoint 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj163800.aspx)

Comment: Thank you. I know about server API, but I work with SharePoint Online, so it is not my case. I'll be looking for alternatives.

Comment: User profile properties are now writable via CSOM http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2014/11/07/sharepoint-user-profile-properties-now-writable-with-csom.aspx