# How can I pass authentication for asmx service in SharePoint 2013 (Online)?

Tags: web-services, sharepoint-online, asmx

I found that CSOM API don't allow modifying user profiles properties in SharePoint 2013, but this function is still in asmx user profile service.
I know that SharePoint online uses oAuth for authentication.
How can I pass authentication in SharePoint Online App for asmx service? Is it even possible?

My case is SharePoint 2013 Online, not on-premise.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [blog post about active authentication](http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/How-to-do-active-authentication-to-Office-365-and-SharePoint-Online.aspx) for SharePoint Online, it helped me.

Only one think I corrected to use it with asmx service, I didn't use client context, I used HttpWebRequest and initialized it's CookieContainer with CookieContainer of current HttpWebRequest after passing authentication with MsOnlineClaimsHelper class.

Note: It doesn't work for domain federation.